# CORS bloqueia as requisições

Tags: spring-boot, cors

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web com Vue JS em uma disciplina e outro pessoal está fazendo uma api rest com Spring, porém quando  rodo a api localmente e tento acessar alguns dos recursos pelo Postman, funciona normalmente, mas ao acessar o mesmo recurso pela aplicação web o CORS bloqueia e a requisição nem chega a api. O mesmo acontece se a api estiver hospedada no Heroku por exemplo.

Já foi adicionada em todos os controllers essa anotação
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E na aplicação VUE JS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O token eu também guardo no localStorage e defino como cabeçalho padrão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei desativando e ativando essa extensão e fica do mesmo jeito
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei mais o que fazer :/

Answer (score 0):

Tente deste jeito, vá na sua classe de configuração, esta classe esta anotada com @Configuration se não tiver crie uma, e crie o seguinte Bean:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.setMaxAge(3600L);

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Algumas configurações mudam de versão para versão do spring, então quando for perguntar sempre informe as versões que você está usando.